# Swift for in loop: use var get warning to use let, use let get error

Tags: swift

I have the following code in a swift file:

```
func testDictionary(dict :Dictionary<String,AnyObject>) {
    var str = ""
    for var key in dict.keys {
        str += key + ":" + dict[key]!.description + "\n"
    }
    self.alert("Dict", message: str)
}
```

The above code produces a warning on the user of `var` in the `for` loop, which is:

```
Variable 'key' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant
```

However when I change `var` to `let` I get the following error:

```
'let' pattern cannot appear nested in an already immutable context
```

Why do I get a warning when the suggested correction is a compiler error?

Comment: Just `for key in dict.keys { ... }`.

Answer (score 28):

**Neither** **var** **nor** **let** is needed in the statement.
Type this:

```
for key in dict.keys {
    str += key + ":" + dict[key]!.description + "\n"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've upvoted, but this doesn't actually answer the question, which is  'Why do I get a warning when the suggested correction is a compiler error?'

Comment: It's simple. IDE at Xcode Beta is still not such smart. It warns you that you shouldn't use var, but it notes it would be better to use let, regardless it leads to an error...

Comment: This happens in XCode 7, it's not a beta.

Comment: I agree, this answer is advisory, but it is not actually an answer.  It would be great if we could have the problem explained.  Will change my downvote to upvote when that happens.

Comment: After seeing other comments, I feel obligated to add that this is still the case in Xcode 10.3 and likely will be in 11 as well. Not sure how earlier version handled it, but in Xcode 10.3, removing the qualifier completely as suggested in the answer still works but I still get a warning suggesting that I use 'let' since it is never mutated.

Comment: > t's simple. IDE at Xcode Beta is still not such smart. // and yet, 6 years later, I we still gave this meaningless warning message...

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer here is that the for-in loop by default provides a key that is already a constant.  Therefore using the let keyword is redundant.  When you used the var keyword, you were saying you wanted a variable key, but you never change it, therefore you don't need to use var.